# Uninitialized external drive cannot be erased

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

I have a StoreJet Transcend hard drive. It suddenly stopped working. When I plugged it in my mac shows that it's not readable. I tried restarting my Mac.

[image: The disk you attached was not readable by this computer.]

Then when it didn't work, I clicked initialize and it opens Disk Utility. I tried running first aid but it doesn't work. I also accessed disk utility in recovery mode as well. And finally, I tried to erase it but it always ends up in error even with the security option at most secure. I even tried updating my OS.

[image: Error: unable to write to the last block of the device.]

The main reason I could think about is it's not properly ejected. My sister often use my mac and she always forgets to eject the drive properly. I'm at a loss on what to do. There are some important files inside.
This is how it looks in Disk Utility:

[image: Disk Utility screenshot]

Comment: If your goal is to recover data why are you trying so hard to permanently erase it? 'Initialise' is bad enough, but 'secure erase' is going to try to destroy that data beyond all hopes of recovery. "unable to write to last block" is often a physical connectivity issue - see https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136601/error-unable-to-write-to-the-last-block-of-the-device Unplugging any device without unmounting it is dangerous, though. Education is required… or don't let other people use it.

Comment: Do you want to recover or to erase this disk?

Comment: If possible, I want to recover.